# MySQL JOIN Multiple tables not working

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure why this isn't working. If I join either table separately, it comes back with the appropriate results, but when I try to join them both, I get 0 results. (car_id and boat_id are both primary keys on their tables.)

```
$query = "SELECT
             *
        FROM            
            posted c
            JOIN posted_car e on c.car_id = e.car_id
            JOIN posted_boat g on c.boat_id = g.boat_id
        WHERE
            c.posted = 'posted'
            ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 30";
        $resultBoth = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
```

Might be worth noting that when I do

```
LEFT JOIN posted_car e on c.car_id = e.car_id
RIGHT JOIN posted_boat g on c.boat_id = g.boat_id
```

I get results as if I had only joined the posted_boat table. If anyone could point me in the right direction...it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @YotamOmer It's shorthand for creating an alias in MySQL. @noWayhome I would guess that `posted.car_id` and `posted.boat_id` are unlikely to both be non-`NULL` at the same time. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using JOIN that might be a problem . you should use left outer join to get proper result . check following syntax :

```
$query = "SELECT *
    FROM            
        posted c
        left OUTER JOIN posted_car e on c.car_id = e.car_id
        left OUTER JOIN posted_boat g on c.boat_id = g.boat_id
    WHERE c.posted = 'posted'
        ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 30";
    $resultBoth = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
```

Comment: please don't forgot to select this ans as valid ans if it helps you . it might help others .